# Want to invert BOOL value in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, boolean

I am getting id values from plist in iOS sdk,  if i am getting value 0 then I  have to show it as 1 and vice versa.

Here is my code for the same

```
+(BOOL) removeButton {
   id obj = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"ABC"];
   if (obj != Nil) {
      return (BOOL)obj;
  }
    return YES;
 }
```

But the problem is that as the value for id is 0 then it will return No and vice versa. But I want to put my condition in opposite matter such as suppose the value for id is 0 then I have to show return YES and vice versa.

Comment: what's "`Nil`" defined as?  it should be "`nil`" (all lower case) or "`NULL`".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cast `id` to `BOOL`.  Assuming it is stored correctly, the way you get it out of a dictionary is through the number wrapper `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumber *boolWrapper = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"ABC"];
return ![boolWrapper boolValue];
```

This will return 0 for 1 and 1 for 0.

If you simply cast it like you are doing, it will always be true unless the object doesn't exist (i.e. it is `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

Add "!" as below :)

```
return !(BOOL)obj;
```

[Edit]

And you should use objectForInfoDictionaryKey this instead of valueForKey as below:

```
id object = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:"Key"];
```

Comment: And you should use objectForInfoDictionaryKey this instead of valueForKey as below:
id object = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:"Key"];

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something like this:

```
+(BOOL) removeButton {
   id obj = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"ABC"];
   BOOL shouldRemoveButton = N0;
   if (obj != nil) {
      shouldRemoveButton = YES;
  }
    return shouldRemoveButton;
 }
```

I don't like to have `returns`in the middle of the code, it makes it confuse and not very clear.

Comment: Hello Jack I am getting 0 or 1 value from plist so I have to to perform like that only